# How do you add a package (or a mirror?) if the .rpm you're looking for isn't available in your VM build of CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I have yum and rpm, and I really only know how to install packages using these commands. When I tried to yum install figlet on a new CentOS6 virtual machine it couldn't find it in the mirrors list. I tried to localinstall a figlet package but it wasn't signed and yum wouldn't install it.

OR

better yet how do you got about adding a package (or a mirror?) if the .rpm you're looking for isn't availabe in your VM build of CentOS?

In this case I want to add figlet and toilet!

**UPDATE**
If I install a package manually, do I need to do it from a particular directory? or does Yum/RPM have a dir they always use automagically?

Comment: Find the RPM, download it manually, and use `rpm -i` (as I recall; it's been a long time since I've used redhat.)

Comment: I did download it locally and did yum localinstall but it complained that the package wasnt signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/figlet/) you can download the figlet packge and install it with `rpm -U` or `rpm -ivh package.rpm`, or do `yum localinstall --nogpgcheck packgename`.

You don't need to run the `yum` command from a particular directory.

As a general recommendation, I encourge you to add the [RpmForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) repos to you centos installation, since it includes a lot of programs.

Comment: I've tried `sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck figlet-2.2.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Cannot open: figlet-2.2.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do` - Can someone please help ?